# How to redirect properly in Django URL , I am having issue in redirecting

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-users

- Having issue with redirecting, I am at registration page("accounts/register") on my website where I want if someone register then a verification code will send on his email id and to verify we have a url "accounts/verify". but when I am trying to register it register a user but does not send them on "accounts/verify" instead it send that to "accounts/register/accounts/verify" ,
- Also please let me know how to use user email address, while registering him into database. I just want his email id to send verification code.

> Here is my URL.py of my app:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    urlpatterns = [
        path('login/', views.login, name='Login-Page'),
        path('register/', views.register, name='Registeration-page'),
        path('logout/', views.logout),
        path('verify/', views.verify, name='verification page')
```

> Here is my View.py for registration and profile:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import requests
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages
from datetime import date
import smtplib
import random
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']

        if password1==password2:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, "Username already taken")
                return redirect('accounts/register')
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, "email already taken")
                return redirect('accounts/register')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password1, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
                user.save();  
                return redirect('accounts/verify') # 'accounts/login'
        else:
            messages.info(request,"password not matched")
            return redirect('accounts/register')

    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')


def verify(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sender_address = 'xyz@gmail.com'
        sender_pass = 'password'
        user_email = register.user.objects.email
        receiver_address = user_email
        passd = random.randrange(111111,10000000,39)
        mail_content = "Hello This is your verficatiob code   " + str(passd)

        def check(code):
            if code==passd:
                return redirect('accounts/login')
            else:
                messages.info(request,"Code is incorrect")
                return redirect('accounts/verify')


        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message['From'] = sender_address
        message['To'] = receiver_address
        message['Subject'] = 'Verification Code'
        message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
        session = smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT)
        session.starttls()
        session.login(sender_address, sender_pass)
        text = message.as_string()
        session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
        session.quit()
        print('Mail Sent')
        code = request.POST['code']

        check(code)
    else:
        return render(request, 'email_verify.html')
```

> Here is my register template:

```
<div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url ('/images/bg-01.jpg');">
            <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-65 p-b-54">
                <form action="{{register}}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                <!--<form class="login100-form validate-form">-->
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-49">
                        Registration
                    </span>
                    <div>
                    {% for message in messages %}
                    <input class="wrap-input validate-input m-b-23" data-validate="{{message}}">
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "First name is reauired">
                        <span class="label-input100"><th>first name</th></span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Type your First name">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "Last name is reauired">
                        <span class="label-input100"><th>last name</th></span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Type your Last name">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Username is required">
                        <span class="label-input100">Username</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="username" name="username" placeholder="Type your username">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf190;"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="email is required">
                        <span class="label-input100">email</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Type your email">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf190;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="password is required">
                        <span class="label-input100">Password</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Type your password">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf190;"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="confirm password is required">
                        <span class="label-input100">Confirm Password</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Type your password Again">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf190;"></span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <button class="login100-form-btn">
                                Register
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

> This is the error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    localhost/accounts/register/accounts/verify
Using the URLconf defined in made.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='Homepage']
accounts/ login/ [name='Login-Page']
accounts/ register/ [name='Registeration-page']
accounts/ logout/
accounts/ verify/ [name='verification page']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    urlpatterns = [
        path('login/', views.login, name='Login-Page'),
        path('register/', views.register, name='Registeration-page'),
        path('logout/', views.logout),
        path('verify/', views.verify, name='verificationPage')
```

#

```
def verify(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sender_address = 'xyz@gmail.com'
        sender_pass = 'password'
        user_email = register.user.objects.email
        receiver_address = user_email
        passd = random.randrange(111111,10000000,39)
        mail_content = "Hello This is your verficatiob code   " + str(passd)

        def check(code):
            if code==passd:
                return redirect('accounts/login')
            else:
                messages.info(request,"Code is incorrect")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('verificationPage')) # you'r issus
                #Or    return HttpResponseRedirect("/Yourapp/verify")
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message['From'] = sender_address
        message['To'] = receiver_address
        message['Subject'] = 'Verification Code'
        message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
        session = smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT)
        session.starttls()
        session.login(sender_address, sender_pass)
        text = message.as_string()
        session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
        session.quit()
        print('Mail Sent')
        code = request.POST['code']

        check(code)
    else:
        return render(request, 'email_verify.html')
```

Comment: Salah can you also tell me How I can use user email to send him a email , please share this as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add **/**(slash) to beginnig of URL like how you did in  `return redirect('accounts/verify')`, it will be added on current URL and you will unfortunately will be redirected to **"accounts/register/accounts/verify"** which is not defined. You need to change all like `return redirect('/accounts/verify')`. Or, my advice is representing them by their name. In this case, it would be `return redirect('verification page')`.

And here is how I could send an email, a bit different from your way. But it worked fine on my project.

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND ="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "youremailadress@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "yourpassword"
```

views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail("subject","message", EMAIL_HOST_USER, ["recipient@gmail.com"])
```

Comment: Mehmet can you also ttell me How I can use user email to send him a email , please share this as well.

Comment: Sorry, I am newbie as well , and trying to implement this feature on my website. But still couldn't success. I hope another person will answer your question soon. It would help me, too :)

Comment: I edited my answer and wrote how to send emails, please check it and let me know if it works fine

Comment: Mehmet thats way also work fine , but I had issue that , when I am generating code , I cant save that in user database and and use that code on following steps to verify , thanks for your support ,